# Proper configuration for Jenkins GitHub Pull Request Builder downstream

Tags: git, github, jenkins, ghprb

I'm trying to create two Jenkins jobs that both leverage the [GitHub Pull Request Builder plugin](https://github.com/janinko/ghprb) in order to run multiple status checks, but I'm having trouble getting the status check from my downstream job to show up in my GitHub project.

Here's the summarized CI flow I'd like to setup:

1. A pull request is opened against my git repository which triggers **Upstream** job to run in Jenkins
2. **Upstream** reports its status based on the build and, if `SUCCESS`, should invoke **Downstream** job via a post-build action
3. **Downstream** runs and reports its own status check

Step 3 is where I'm having issues. **Downstream** runs properly, but it does not post a status. The status is not even available under the **Branches** section of my GitHub project's settings. I'm not sure how [GHPRB](https://github.com/janinko/ghprb) does the initial creation of the status check, but there are references to the context messaging in the Console Output:

```
14:58:23 Started by upstream project "upstream" build number 209
14:58:23 originally caused by:
14:58:23  GitHub pull request #114 of commit f1ff2819a5308f7819275e732cf44a2cc2ec31dc, no merge conflicts.
14:58:23 [EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
14:58:23 Building on master in workspace /store/jenkins/jobs/downstream/workspace
14:58:23  > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
14:58:23 Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
14:58:23  > git config remote.origin.url <removed for privacy> # timeout=10
14:58:23 Fetching upstream changes from <removed for privacy>
14:58:23  > git --version # timeout=10
14:58:23  > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress <removed for privacy> +refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
14:58:24  > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
14:58:24  > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
14:58:24 Checking out Revision eac390c51a1b8b591bfe879421bd5fad0421a1ec (refs/remotes/origin/master)
14:58:24  > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
14:58:24  > git checkout -f eac390c51a1b8b591bfe879421bd5fad0421a1ec
14:58:24 First time build. Skipping changelog.
14:58:24 [build] $ /store/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Ant_AntInstallation/ant_1.8.2/bin/ant -DghprbStatusUrl= "-DghprbSUCCESSMessage=Packaging organization successfully cleaned" -DghprbStartedStatus=Undeploying -DghprbAddTestResults=false "-DghprbCommitStatusContext=Cleaning Packaging" "-DghprbERRORMessage=An error occurred during undeployment" -DghprbUpstreamStatus=true "-DghprbTriggeredStatus=Preparing destructive changes" "-DghprbFAILUREMessage=Packaging organization failed to clean properly" -DghprbShowMatrixStatus=false
```

Here are the relevant configuration sections for both Jenkins jobs:

---

### Upstream Job

#### Source Code Management: Git

- Name: `origin`
- Refspec: `+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*`
- Branch Specifier: `${sha1}`

#### Build Triggers

- GitHub Pull Request Builder

  - Use github hooks for build triggering `✔︎`
  - Display build errors on downstream builds? `✔︎`
  - **Trigger Setup** is populated with custom context messaging

#### Post-build Actions

- Build other projects: `Downstream`

---

### Downstream Job

#### Source Code Management: Git

- Name: `origin`
- Refspec: `+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*`
- Branch Specifier: `*/master`

#### Build Triggers

- GitHub Pull Request Builder

  - **Trigger Setup** is populated with custom context messaging

#### Build Environment

- Set GitHub commit status with custom context and message (Must configure upstream job using GHPRB trigger) `✔︎`

  - Custom context messaging fields mirror those listed under the **Trigger Setup** section (I doubt both of these are required, but neither seem to be working currently)

---

What am I missing? **It should be noted** that I do not have the Jobs DSL plugin installed so I cannot leverage [the extension that GHPRB provides](https://github.com/janinko/ghprb#job-dsl-support).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After extensive trial and error, [this comment](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/issues/326#issuecomment-232085433) shed some light on my issue.

### The crux of my issue was that **Downstream** was not receiving required environment variables that [GHPRB](https://github.com/janinko/ghprb) provides. Namely `ghprbGhRepository`, `ghprbPullId`, `ghprbActualCommit` and `sha1`.

The correct configurations for both jobs are as follows:

---

### Upstream Job

#### Source Code Management: Git

- Name: `origin`
- Refspec: `+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*`
- Branch Specifier: `${sha1}`

#### Build Triggers

- GitHub Pull Request Builder

  - Use github hooks for build triggering `✔︎`
  - Display build errors on downstream builds? `✔︎`
  - **Trigger Setup** is populated with custom context messaging

#### Build

- [Trigger/call builds on other projects](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)

  - Projects to build: `Downstream`
  - Predefined parameters:

    - `ghprbGhRepository=${ghprbGhRepository}`
    - `ghprbPullId=${ghprbPullId}`
    - `ghprbActualCommit=${ghprbActualCommit}`
    - `sha1=${sha1}`

---

### Downstream Job

#### Source Code Management: Git

- Name: `origin`
- Refspec: `+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*`
- Branch Specifier: `${sha1}`

#### Build Environment

- Set GitHub commit status with custom context and message (Must configure upstream job using GHPRB trigger) `✔︎`

Comment: What if we want to add git status checks on upstream PR repo with downstream job which uses different git repo and different branch?

Comment: I've noticed you removed the build trigger in the dowstream job as well. Is it intentional?